# Service cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

This is driving me nuts because the answer is probably staring me in the face.   I'm trying to learn to make a simple service in Android using the example in http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html
But where I try to start my service

```
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

I get "MyService cannot be resolved to a type" at build-time.

The example has this line in the Manifest just after the close of activity and before the close of application . . .

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
```

... but I've also tried it without the "." and with a fully qualified package name, i.e., test.bg.MyService, with no improvement.

Any idea why it can't resolve it?

Comment: They are in the same package:  test.bg....

Comment: Try clean and re-build your project, sometimes change doesn't auto-saved and re-compiled in some IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting "MyService cannot be resolved to a type" during the compile, or as an error from Eclipse, then there is no such class in your project.

It has nothing to do with your manifest -- problems stemming from that will not show up until runtime with the current crop of developer tools.

Comment: Of course there's no such class in the project -  a service is built as a separate project.      How is a service conventionally resolved in android?     In the example link I posted above there is no "import" for the service class in the client, so how is it usually resolved in Android?

Comment: In the android documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample it says a service can "supply functionality for other applications to use" - that's what I'm trying to write -  not a service that's part of one application.  Where can I see how to do this?

Comment: @user316117: You start by reading MisterSquonk's answer. A service is **always** "part of one application". Whether it **additionally** exposes something for third parties is a separate matter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you read the documentation on [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) especially the parts about *Explicit* and *Implicit* Intents.

What you are trying to do is use an *Explicit* Intent to start a Service using a class name which doesn't exist in the project that is attempting to start it (as CommonsWare points out).

As for your belief that...

> a service is built as a separate project

...that may be possible but very often that isn't the case and even your link in your comment to CommonsWare actually demonstrates the use of a [Local Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) and to quote from the opening paragraph of that section...

> One of the most common uses of a Service is as a secondary component running alongside other parts of an application, in the same process as the rest of the components. All components of an .apk run in the same process unless explicitly stated otherwise, so this is a typical situation.

So basically that's saying that a typical situation is that your Service will be a component of an application containing other components which will make use of that Service.

Sure, you can use a Service in another application but you need to register it in your manifest with an `<intent-filter>` entry and an action such as `test.bg.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING` and then have an external application start it using an *Implicit* Intent.

Using the example code you linked in your question isn't going to work.

Comment: I tried wrapping it in an intent filter in the manifest and that didn't work either.  Is the only way to have a client from one project call a service in another to use AIDL?